# How can I change the order in subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I change the order of execution? I have an array `this.friend`, I need work with this array, but it takes to fill up with data

```
this.listUserService.getUsers().subscribe(
    async (data: any) => {
           this.listUsers = data;
           await data.forEach((current: any) => {
                 if (current.name === userSession) {
                      this.user = current;
                      this.friendsService.getFriends(this.user.id).subscribe(response => {
                                console.log('last', response);//this runs second
                                this.friends = response;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('friends', this.friends); //friend is clear, 
this runs first
                    this.listUsers = this.listUsers.filter(user => !this.friends.some(relationship => relationship[0].friend.id !== user.id));
                }
            );
```

The console messages are shown in reverse order, how can I change the order, once it's full I want to use the Filter function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mix promises with observables. In addition, it is not a good idea to nest `subscribe()` methods within each other. I would recommend you to handle the above operation with RxJS operators.

First, we use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to map over the observable values from the getUsers() method from the service, into an inner observable.

Then, we use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to wait the `Array.forEach()` loop to be completed before returning all the observables. Since you seem to be familiar with the usage of Promises in JavaScript, it is actually similar to `Promise.all`.

Last but not least, we handle the filtering of the `listUsers` at the `subscribe()` block. This will ensure that your asynchronous code is properly handle.

```
this.listUserService.getUsers().pipe(
  mergeMap(data => {
    this.listUsers = data;
    const observablesList = [];
    data.forEach((current: any) => {
      if (current.name === userSession) {
        observablesList.push(this.friendsService.getFriends(current.id));
      }
    });
    return forkJoin(observablesList);
  })
).subscribe(response => {
  // console.log(response) will give you the returned values from the looped getFriends()
  // handle the rest here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try instead using RxJS operators such as [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html), and [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) to control the flow of the observable including performing side effects like setting class properties.

This answer assumes that there is only a single current user resulting from `if (current.name === userSession) {` inside the forEach() and subsequently that `this.friendsService.getFriends(user.id)` only executes once.

```
import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'; // need to import operators

// ...

this.listUserService.getUsers().pipe(
  tap(users => this.listUsers = users), // side effect to set this.listUsers
  map(users => users.find(user => user.name === userSession)), // find current user
  switchMap(user => this.friendsService.getFriends(user.id)), // get friends of current user
  tap(friends => this.friends = friends), // side effect to set this.friends
  map(friends => this.listUsers.filter(user => this.friends.some(relationship => relationship[0].friend.id !== user.id)))
).subscribe(listUsers => {
  this.listUsers = listUsers;
});
```

You should definitely review the RxJS documentation for more information and examples of the various operators. Also you will definitely need to improve error handling in case situations like a current user is not found or any of the service/api calls fail.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using RxJS streams in the wrong way. You setup your stream first, so any other `console.log` would run first. The Rx stream is async by itself, so you don't need `async await`. The other `console.log` will run when the stream actually is called and receives data.

The RxJS way would be to `.pipe()` your `filter()` inside the Rx stream.

It's not so much an Angular problem, it's more RxJS related. Here's an example of what it could look like:

```
   this.listUserService
  .getUsers()
  .pipe(
    tap(listUserData => {
      this.listUsers = listUserData;
    }),
    switchMap(data => {
      return this.friendsService.getFriends(data.id).pipe(
        tap(friends => {
          this.friends = friends;
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

The `switchMap` switches to another observable underwater, so you don't need two subscriptions. This is considered good practice!

I would highly recommend spending some time learning RxJS, it'll make your experiences in Angular much more enjoyable and productive!

I can help you out with that if you'd like!